# Extract H, S, L values from color using SASS

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

Given a hex color (or any other format), is it possible to get the H, S, L values in SASS and put them in separate CSS variables?

```
$colors: ( "primary": $primary, "secondary": $secondary) !default;
:root {
    @each $color, $value in $colors {
        --#{$color}-h: #{$value};
        --#{$color}-s: #{$value};
        --#{$color}-l: #{$value};
      }
}
```

Currently, the code above just prints the color 3 times. Is it possible to achieve this in SASS?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I did it using a combination of SASS functions.

```
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
    --#{$color}-h: #{str-slice(quote(hue($value)), 1, -4)};
    --#{$color}-s: #{saturation($value)};
    --#{$color}-l: #{lightness($value)};
  }
```